# Can't express the join expression

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, syntax-error

I found a similar question on SO but the solution said to remove an extra set of parentheses. I did that, but then it gives me a new error - "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression". I don't see another set of parentheses that I could probably remove besides the set I have noted with asterisks below. (I focused on the fact that the solution said **set** of parentheses). Now I'm just removing more and more parentheses in the hopes that I stumble upon which set is causing the problem. Any ideas?

**EDIT** The whole error message is "**Microsoft Access can't represent the join expression dbo_jobmatl.suffix = dbo_job.suffix in Design View.**" "One or more fields may have been deleted or renamed; The name of one or more fields or tables specified in the join exression may be misspelled; The join may use an operator that isn't supported in Design view, such as > or <."

```
 SELECT dbo_jobmatl.item, dbo_job.whse
FROM **(**(dbo_job INNER JOIN dbo_jobmatl ON (dbo_jobmatl.suffix = dbo_job.suffix) AND (dbo_job.job = dbo_jobmatl.job)**)** INNER JOIN dbo_ISW_LPLot ON dbo_jobmatl.item = dbo_ISW_LPLot.item) INNER JOIN (dbo_location INNER JOIN dbo_ISW_LP ON dbo_location.loc = dbo_ISW_LP.loc) ON dbo_job.whse = dbo_ISW_LP.whse
GROUP BY dbo_job.job, dbo_job.suffix, dbo_job.item, dbo_job.job_date, dbo_jobmatl.item, dbo_job.whse, [qty_released]*[matl_qty], dbo_jobmatl.qty_issued, ([qty_released]*[matl_qty])-[qty_issued]
HAVING (((dbo_job.job) Not Like "BM*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "QCBEN*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "QCBRU*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "QCKIR*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "SS*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "SU*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "TR*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "WC*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "WH*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "WT*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "KR*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "HR*") And ((dbo_job.item) Not Like "Indirect") And ((dbo_job.job_date)=Forms!MainForm!Text0));
```

Comment: Is there more to that error? Does it say where the Syntax Error is? Can you double check to insure that your Forms!MainForm!Text0 has a value that is a date. Lastly, for fun, throw some [brackets] around each element in the Form reference like [Forms]![MainForm]![Text0]. My guess is that this has nothing to do with Parentheses.

Comment: Yes there is more to the error, I will edit. Sorry about that.

Comment: Have you tried building the query in the Access visual editor rather than writing the SQL by hand? It could be that you've misspelled a field name or something simple like that.

Comment: Test a new simple query to investigate that join expression complaint.  Does Access still complain about this one? `SELECT * FROM dbo_job INNER JOIN dbo_jobmatl ON (dbo_job.suffix = dbo_jobmatl.suffix) AND (dbo_job.job = dbo_jobmatl.job)`

Comment: @citizenkong The weird thing is that I created this in Design View, was having ODBC errors every time I tried to go to Datasheet view, so I saved it and closed it. The next day (today) I reopened it and tried to go to Design view but it gave me the "Microsoft Access can't represent the join expression dbo_jobmatl.suffix = dbo_job.suffix in Design View." error.

Comment: @HansUp I pasted your code and it loaded the Datasheet and Design view with no errors. That's pretty strange because the error message pointed to that section of the code as problematic.

Comment: That's not what I expected, but build on that working query.  Join the next table and test.  Keep the rest of the query simple for now --- `SELECT *` only, and no `GROUP BY` or `HAVING`.

Comment: @HansUP Ok I will and I'll post any new and relevant findings when they come up. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    dbo_jobmatl.item
    , dbo_job.whse
FROM 
    dbo_job 
    INNER JOIN dbo_jobmatl ON (dbo_jobmatl.suffix = dbo_job.suffix) AND (dbo_job.job = dbo_jobmatl.job) 
    INNER JOIN dbo_ISW_LPLot ON dbo_jobmatl.item = dbo_ISW_LPLot.item 
    INNER JOIN (dbo_location ON dbo_location.loc = dbo_ISW_LP.loc)
    INNER JOIN dbo_ISW_LP ON dbo_job.whse = dbo_ISW_LP.whse
GROUP BY 
    dbo_job.job, dbo_job.suffix, dbo_job.item, dbo_job.job_date, dbo_jobmatl.item, dbo_job.whse, [qty_released]*[matl_qty], dbo_jobmatl.qty_issued, ([qty_released]*[matl_qty])-[qty_issued]
HAVING 
    (((dbo_job.job) Not Like "BM*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "QCBEN*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "QCBRU*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "QCKIR*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "SS*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "SU*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "TR*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "WC*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "WH*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "WT*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "KR*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "HR*") And ((dbo_job.item) Not Like "Indirect") And ((dbo_job.job_date)=Forms!MainForm!Text0));
```

I pasted your query text into gedit, set the syntax highlighting to SQL, and then went to work formatting it.  This let me see that some of the join syntax for dbo_location got mixed into the join syntax for dbo_ISQ_LP.  I haven't reviewed your HAVING syntax.

Comment: I pasted it in and it didn't work :( It gave me the error "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(dbo_jobmatl.suffix = dbo_job.suffix.............................INNER JOIN dbo_ISW_LP ON dbo_job.whse = dbo_ISW_LP.whs'. The "....." indicates everything in between.

In case you're wondering, the error message seems to cut off the "whse" as "whs". However this is not the case. In the sql I paste, it is spelled correctly. It seems like the error message just ran out of room.

Comment: This join expression isn't compatible with Access syntax - it needs parentheses around each part of the join. It's an odd beast.

Comment: @citizenkong I placed parentheses around the terms that are related by an equal sign, such as (dbo_jobmatl.item = dbo_ISW_LPLot.item), however I still get the same error. Should I have put them around some other set of terms?